# How to train multiple inputs for my model?

Tags: machine-learning, training, object-detection

I'm a high school student and a newbie in Machine Learning. I just learned Machine Learning Crash Course by Google so my knowledge's still limited.
I'm trying to build an Object Detection by myself and get into trouble.

That is,
I have a dataset as below:

```
    xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax      name
0     31   155    56   179  pendulum
1    157   150   178   172  pendulum
2    151    65   173    88  pendulum
3     67    32    88    54  pendulum
4    178   214   212   246  pendulum
..   ...   ...   ...   ...       ...
42    93   225   108   244  pendulum
43   133   246   151   262  pendulum
44    59   175    71   188  pendulum
45   176   113   190   126  pendulum
46   114    87   124    99  pendulum

[47 rows x 5 columns]
```

And my question is How do I train all of these features xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax to my model? In Machine Learning Crash Course I just learned how to train a model with a single feature, so in this case, I'm so confused.

Hope everyone helps me